# How to read frame in OpenCV2 python

Tags: python, opencv, numpy

This is in regards to this piece of code:

```
image1 = cv.QueryFrame( self.cap )
```

This works in opencv, however, I'm trying to do this in OpenCV2 now using this code:

```
image1 = self.cap.read(self.cap)
```

This code is giving me an error:

> TypeError: image is not a numpy array, neither a scalar

I'm confused as to why this isn't working, because when looking at the documentation for OpenCV it says that these two are equivalent, or are they?

Comment: please use cv2, not the deprecated cv api(which will no more be available in opencv3.0)

Comment: Yes that is what I'm trying to do, I have some old code that I'm trying to update from cv to cv2 however I'm having a little difficulty with this bit here.

Comment: `cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0); ok,frame = cap.read();`